VBA for Vlookup with multiple criteria
I have a worksheet where I have a mixture of manual and automated input. I am trying to write some VBA code to first check if a cell in range is blank, and only if it is, pull date from a sheet of dates but only return the date if it is greater than or equal to today. Case numbers are in column A on both sheets but I can't figure out how to reference them.
This is what I have so far. It returns no errors but is not pulling the data through either.
Sub LookUpBlankDatesSA()

    Dim wsOpenCases As Worksheet
    Dim wsSADates As Worksheet
    Dim lastRow As Long
    Dim i As Long
    
    ' Set references to the relevant sheets
    Set wsOpenCases = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("OpenCasesSummary")
    Set wsSADates = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("SA Dates")
    
    ' Find the last row in column J
    lastRow = wsOpenCases.Cells(wsOpenCases.Rows.Count, "J").End(xlUp).Row
    
    ' Loop through the rows
    For i = 4 To lastRow
        If IsEmpty(wsOpenCases.Cells(i, "J").Value) Then
            ' Check if the date in SA Dates is greater than or equal to today
            If wsSADates.Cells(i, "B").Value >= Date Then
                ' Update the value in OpenCasesSummary
                wsOpenCases.Cells(i, "J").Value = wsSADates.Cells(i, "B").Value
            End If
        End If
    Next i

End Sub


Minor comment: lastRow = wsOpenCases.Cells(wsOpenCases.Rows.Count, "J").End(xlUp).Row will skip any subsequent empty cases: i.e. if you have data in rows 4–20, but rows 8, 14, 18, 19, and 20 are blank in Column J, then your code will loop from row 4 to row 17 (and only fill out rows 8 and 14).  Try something like With wsOpenCases.Cells(3, "J").CurrentRegion: lastRow = .Rows(.Rows.Count).Row: End With perhaps?  Or, just grab it on the Case Number column?  (lastRow = wsOpenCases.Cells(wsOpenCases.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row) I assume that will be a "Mandatory" key field?

There is also information missing. Will there be duplicate case numbers in the "SA Dates" worksheet? I'm guessing so, because some will be before today and others will be after today for the same case number. In the event of multiple case numbers with a date greater than today, should only the date closest to today be returned? Or some other method to determine which is the correct date to return?

However, more directly: why not use Application.MaxIfs(..) or Application.MinIfs(..) to get the date to a temporary variable, and discard if the value is zero?

Thanks for the responses - just to clarify, there are no duplicates of case numbers on SA Dates, and the case numbers are a mandatory field. Will try the suggested amendment above and report back :)

So it's pulling dates through but for the same line, not in reference to the case number. I think I need to start again with a vlookup script.

If you need to match rows based on case number:
Sub LookUpBlankDatesSA()

    Dim wsOpenCases As Worksheet, wsSADates As Worksheet
    Dim lastRow As Long, i As Long, m As Variant, c As Range, dt
    
    Set wsOpenCases = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("OpenCasesSummary")
    Set wsSADates = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("SA Dates")
    
    'Find the last row in #Col A#
    lastRow = wsOpenCases.Cells(wsOpenCases.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    
    For i = 4 To lastRow ' Loop through the rows
        Set c = wsOpenCases.Cells(i, "J")
        If IsEmpty(c.Value) Then 'no date?
            'try to find the matching case number on "SA Dates"
            m = Application.Match(wsOpenCases.Cells(i, "A").Value, wsSADates.Columns("A"), 0)
            If Not IsError(m) Then                   'got a match?
                dt = wsSADates.Cells(i, "B").Value   'read the date
                If dt >= Date Then c.Value = dt       'add if > Today
            End If  'got match
        End If      'empty date
    Next i
End Sub

